# how to refresh google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem:

1. I placed markers on a map
2. I filter data and want to place part of these markers => I send json to server
3. I get response, delete all markers and try to place new markers, but my gmap has gray color and nothing appears.
   here is some piece of code:

   ```
   var pins;

   function processFilterResult(data) {

       pins = data;

       var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pins[0].gpsLocationN, pins[0].gpsLocationW);
       var myOptions = {
           zoom : 7,
           center : myLatlng,
           mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
       for(var i=0; i<pins.length; i++) {
           pins[i] = createMarkers(new google.maps.LatLng(pins[i].gpsLocationN,pins[i].gpsLocationW), pins[i]);
       }
   }

   function initializeGMap() {

       pins = convertToJSON($("#someId"));

       var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pins[0].gpsLocationN, pins[0].gpsLocationW);
       var myOptions = {
           zoom : 7,
           center : myLatlng,
           mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
       for(var i=0; i<pins.length; i++) {
           pins[i] = createMarkers(new google.maps.LatLng(pins[i].gpsLocationN,pins[i].gpsLocationW), pins[i]);
       }
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

       });}
   ```

clear markers:

```
 function clearOverlays() {
          for (var i = 0; i < pins.length; i++ ) {
            pins[i].setMap(null);
          }
          pins = new Array();
    }
```

filtering:

```
      $.post(
                            "/mediabook/owner/filterMaps.json",
                            a,
                            function(data) {
                                clearOverlays();
                                processFilterResult(data);
                            });
```

Comment: you don't want to create a new map object when you add markers, you want to add them to the pre existing object. Important to note the errors that are throw when your code fails

Comment: it was a question or a tip? if tip, thanks for it

Comment: ws a tip regarding errors, look in console, and when have a question include error information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear your entire code though, I think your code should be like this:

```
var map;
function processFilterResult(data) 
{
    pins = data;
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pins[0].gpsLocationN, pins[0].gpsLocationW); 
    map.panTo(myLatLng);
    for(var i=0; i<pins.length; i++) 
    {
        pins[i] = createMarkers(new google.maps.LatLng(pins[i].gpsLocationN,pins[i].gpsLocationW), pins[i]);
    }
}
```